# Function to naming columns

Tags: list-manipulation

I often import files from excel or csv files and they come in a format like this:

```
{{"He", "She", "It", "We"}, {8.57167, 0.406351, 1.68575, 
  5.55309}, {9.16751, 2.57632, 9.20212, 9.8879}, {8.49497, 5.72921, 
  8.92677, 8.17118}, {3.78541, 2.35875, 4.94475, 3.56491}}
```

With dimensions in this case {5,4}, I then want to name the columns by the first row. In this case it would mean that row one would be called he, and is equal to `{8.57167, 9.16751, 8.49497, 3.78541}`. I have tried several ways to do this but some how i keep getting different errors. It should be a very simple and efficient solution.

This would mean that i want {8.57167, 9.16751, 8.49497, 3.78541} to be shown every time i enter he into mathematica, also if the word starts with a capital as it does for all words in this case I would like it to be transformed from He to he and She to she etc.

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do next... do you want to be able to access a particular column by its "name"? If so how do you want it? Rules? `{name, column}` pairs? Or do you just want to display it?

Comment: I want to get {8.57167, 9.16751, 8.49497, 3.78541} if I type He into mathematica.

Comment: Now that's a very important detail you left out! It makes both answers inapplicable to the problem... Please edit your question.

Comment: Of but I just realised If there is a capital I want it to be renamed to in this case he.

Comment: Though I'd say it's generally not a good idea to name variables dynamically.  `something["He"]` returning the data is okay, but once you start naming a variable `He` based on an external dataset, there are so many things that can go wrong (e.g. naming conflicts), not to mention it actually makes it more difficult to do more complex operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this, I would probably use an association or rules instead of storing them in symbols. However, to answer the question asked, this is how you'd do it:

```
With[{symbs = Symbol /@ ToLowerCase@First@data}, Thread[symbs = Rest@data]]
```

Now `He`, `She`, `It` and `We` are symbols containing the respective columns.

Comment: is there any way to remove the Capital letter from He to he

Comment: @ALEXANDER [ToLowerCase](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToLowerCase.html) is the way.

Comment: Could you explain what /. "I" -> "He" does cause I get the same result without it.

Comment: @ALEXANDER I misread your comment and thought you wanted all instances of "I" to be changed to "He". As Oska said, `ToLowerCase` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{"He", "She", "It", "We"}, {8.57167, 0.406351, 1.68575, 
   5.55309}, {9.16751, 2.57632, 9.20212, 9.8879}, {8.49497, 5.72921, 
   8.92677, 8.17118}, {3.78541, 2.35875, 4.94475, 3.56491}}

rules = Rule @@@ Transpose[{First[data], Rest[data]}]
```

In version 9,

```
disp = Dispatch[rules]

"He" /. disp
```

If you have [the v10 beta on a Raspberry Pi](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/),

```
ass = Association[rules]

ass["He"]
```

Comment: `ass["He"]` deserves deep flagging

Answer (score 0):

```
test = {{"He", "She", "It", "We"}, {8.57167, 0.406351, 1.68575, 
   5.55309}, {9.16751, 2.57632, 9.20212, 9.8879}, {8.49497, 5.72921, 
   8.92677, 8.17118}, {3.78541, 2.35875, 4.94475, 3.56491}};

Transpose[{First@test, Transpose@Rest@test}]    

(* 
{{He,{8.57167,9.16751,8.49497,3.78541}},{She,{0.406351,2.57632,5.72921,2.35875}},{It,{1.68575,9.20212,8.92677,4.94475}},{We,{5.55309,9.8879,8.17118,3.56491}}}
*)
```

To actually set symbols, use:

```
Set[Evaluate@ToExpression[#[[1]]], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{First@test, Transpose@Rest@test}]
```

So after evaluating above, input of e.g. "He" evaluates to the list of values.
Be careful using symbol names with uppercase initials...

As noted in some of the comments, in general, better to avoid such dynamic assignments,
better to do say

```
{he, she, it,we}=Transpose[{First@test, Transpose@Rest@test}][[All, 2]]
```

or more succinctly:

```
{he, she, it,we} = Transpose@Rest@test
```